# Find the mode in array

Tags: java, arrays

This code can only get the mode when single mode exist. I want to know how to return -1 when 2 modes exist. For example : 1 1 1 2 2 2 3. And return -1 when no mode exist, 1 2 3 4 5 6.

```
 public Long getMode() {


      long [] num = this.getElements();

      long maxValue=0, maxCount=0; 
      for (int i = 0; i < num.length; ++i){
          long count = 0;
          for (int j = 0; j < num.length; ++j){
              if (num[j] == num[i])
              ++count;
            }
             if (count > maxCount){
              maxCount = count;
              maxValue = num[i];
           }
        }
         return maxValue;
      }
```

Comment: instead of a single value to hold the values you could store the count in an `int[10]` array, whereas each element would represent the occurence of a single number. In the end you´d just have to find the max value in the array, and if it is present twice or more you´d just have to return `-1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine, except that you don't return `-1` if there is no mode, or when 2 modes exist.

For this, you can change your program as follows :
(I have comented the sections I have changed)

```
public static Long getMode() {

    long [] num = this.getElements();
    long maxValue=0, maxCount=0; 
    boolean err = false; // New vraible to check if there is an error.
    for (int i = 0; i < num.length; ++i){
        long count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < num.length; ++j){
            if (num[j] == num[i])
                ++count;
        }
        if(count==maxCount && maxValue!=num[i]){ // if there are two modes
            err=true; // then set err to true.
        }else if (count > maxCount){
            maxCount = count;
            maxValue = num[i];
            err = false; // If valid mode is found, then set err to false.
        }
        System.out.println(err);
    }
    return err ? -1 : maxValue; // return value if err is false, else return -1
}
```